# Java equivalent to app.config?

Tags: java, configuration-files

Is there a Java equivalent to .NET's App.Config?

If not is there a standard way to keep you application settings, so that they can be changed after an app has been distributed?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For WebApps, web.xml can be used to store application settings.

Other than that, you can use the [Properties](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class to read and write properties files.

You may also want to look at the [Preferences](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) class, which is used to read and write system and user preferences.  It's an abstract class, but you can get appropriate objects using the `userNodeForPackage(ClassName.class)` and `systemNodeForPackage(ClassName.class)`.

Comment: Can you give some more information on the first option: "web.xml can be used to store application settings"?
Are you suggesting storing the application settings as `context-param`s?
Or something else?

Comment: There are a few different types of params you can put in web.xml, but I probably did mean `context-param`.  I don't remember as it's been 7.5 years since then.

Answer (score 11):

To put @Powerlord's suggestion (+1) of using the `Properties` class into example code:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String dbUrl = "";
        String dbLogin = "";
        String dbPassword = "";     
        if (args.length<3) {
            //If no inputs passed in, look for a configuration file
            URL configFile = SomeClass.class.getClass().getResource("/Configuration.cnf");
            try {
                InputStream configFileStream = configFile.openStream();
                Properties p = new Properties();
                p.load(configFileStream);
                configFileStream.close();

                dbUrl      = (String)p.get("dbUrl");
                dbLogin    = (String)p.get("dbUser");
                dbPassword = (String)p.get("dbPassword");               
            } catch (Exception e) {  //IO or NullPointer exceptions possible in block above
                System.out.println("Useful message");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        } else {
            //Read required inputs from "args"
            dbUrl      = args[0];
            dbLogin    = args[1];
            dbPassword = args[2];           
        }
        //Input checking one three items here
        //Real work here.
    }
}
```

Then, at the root of the container (e.g. top of a jar file) place a file `Configuration.cnf` with the following content:

```
#Comments describing the file
#more comments
dbUser=username
dbPassword=password
dbUrl=jdbc\:mysql\://servername/databasename
```

This feel not perfect (I'd be interested to hear improvements) but good enough for my current needs.

Comment: Seriously? So you pretty much run the stream reader over the file to get the settings? In the case of multiple classes you will need something like a helper class that can be used across?
Is this the best solution Java can offer here??? It just seems very naive.

Comment: This is the best I could manage, for my needs, in 2013. I believe that the more general solution is generally wrapped up in an application server. The phrase "enterprise java beans" comes to mind, although I have never worked in that environment personally.

Answer (score 2):

The simple way is to simply have a properties file, e.g., myapp.properties, with all your settings in. It's not a very advanced way to do settings but it suffices, or you can have your own XML based setup, or get them from a database, etc.