# Heap Space Issue outside Netbeans IDE

Tags: java, ide, out-of-memory, java-8, netbeans-8

EDIT: I ended up doing a combo of both suggested answers, and thus answered my own question, it is the accepted one below, hopefully this helps others in the future!

I'm running 32 bit Java 1.8.0_40 on Windows 7.

I have created a program in Netbeans 8.0 and adjusted the VM Options to be -Xms512m -Xmx2048m.

The program runs quite well inside the Netbeans IDE environment, however upon trying to run the program outside of Netbeans I encounter a heap space out of memory error.

EDIT: I am launching the program via the .jar file that Netbeans creates for the project upon compilation.

I have gone to the Java control panel and applied the same "-Xms512m -Xmx2048m" information to the Runtime Parameters. I am still encountering the heap space out of memory error.

Any suggestions? Where can I go from here? Have I missed a step in making sure there is enough memory in the Runtime Environment outside of Netbeans?

Comment: Have you tried to pass the VM options to the JVM directly when you run the application?

Comment: No I do not explicitly pass any VM options in my code. I've been struggling to find a clear way to do it, that ISN'T via the command line.

Comment: Please, could you tell us exactly the way you launch your application once outside Netbeans?  Is it some shell script, or an auto-executable JAR file, or any other means?

Comment: @Jorge_B edited to add it to the main question for other to see. Right now I'm simply launching the program via the .jar file that is created in the dist folder by Netbeans upon compilation of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a combination of the two answers. It ended up being that I had to use a fully qualified name enclosed in quotations to execute the command and since others will be using this program I was able to create a .bat file to do so. 
The final .bat file ended up looking like this:

```
java -Xms512m -Xmx2048m -jar "T:\Netbeans Projects\DataLoader\dist\DataLoader.jar"
```

Thank you to both Jorge_B and Sanj for your help! Hopefully this will help other in the future!

Answer (score 4):

The VM options you use in netbeans can also be used on the command line i.e

```
java -Xms512m -Xmx2048m  -jar yourprg.jar
```

There are more [JVM options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) available.

Comment: I have tried to use this command line option, but it does not work for me, my .jar is stored on a network computer. Don't I have to have the .jar on my local machine?  EDIT: Even have placed the .jar and lib folder on my desktop I have gotten a "Error: Unable to access jarfile" message.

Comment: Those jvm options are for the JVM running on your local machine. Does not matter where the jar is sourced from because, it will load and run and use the memory where ever your JVM is located. Unless we are missing something obvious and your are telneting/ssh into a remote box and running the JVM from there.

Comment: Hmmm... No as far as I know I'm not doing anything like that. We have to keep all our projects on a shared local server but we don't do anything special to access them, there isn't an SSH or anything just connect via letter of drives.  I don't have to do a fully qualified address to the .jar or anything like that?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are building an independent JAR file, it looks like there is not a clean way to include such options inside your JAR (some people have asked about it [here](http://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/vm-arguments-in-manifest.129370/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689692/default-arguments-in-jar-manifest) without a definitive answer).  When in your case, my solution is usually to give away a little shell script with the proper -Xms and -Xmx arguments, along with my JAR file.

Comment: When you say "shell script" do you mean a .bat file?

Comment: Yes, that is my idea.  May it suit your problem?  It depends on where are you deploying your software to (there is no reason that you can't write a .bat and a standard .sh version of your launcher, just in case)

Comment: I will give it a shot and report back.